# xcarchive file size increased Xcode 15.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode15

```
app.xcarchive file size 260 Mb (Xcode 14...)
app.xcarchive file size 1.57 Gb (Xcode 15.1)
```

Looked through the package and found that the Assets.car file size has grown from 20 MB to 1.21 GB. No images have been added. How to fix this?